# Using Array Formula with Split()

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet with some data. The data set is likely to grow and I'd like the formula that refer to it on the right to grow with it.

I tried this:

```
=ArrayFormula(split(B16:B,";"))
```

I expected to see the formula copy down the entire length of the sheet (couple of thousand rows) but instead only row 16 produced a result.

Is my understanding of array formula correct? Is there another solution? I could resort to app script but wondered if I was doing something wrong here or if there was a quicker way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split() does not work in Arrayformula. There are workarounds. One involves using regexextract, and looks like this

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(";"&B16:B,"^"&REPT(";+[^;]+",COLUMN(OFFSET(A1,,,1,3))-1)&";+([^;]+)")))
```

The ";" is the delimiter, the "3" would be the maximum splits/column outputs you would have in one cell. E.g: a cell with

value; value; value --> would have a 3 column output when split.

Hope that makes sense ?

EDIT: A recent update (jan 2017) makes it possible to iteratere split() over an array. So something like

```
=ArrayFormula(split(B16:B,";"))
```

should now be possible.